# Using named captures with the branch reset pattern

Tags: regex, perl

```
$recepies =~ s/
                    (?|
                    ([^\.\/]) ($dimentions) 
                    |
                    (\(?) ($wholeNumberDecimal)     #ex: 1.5
                    |
                    (\(?) ($wholeNumber)            #ex: 1
                    |
                    (\(?) ($wholeNumberFraction) 
                    )
                    (\s) ($unit)

                    /transformer($1,$2,$3,$4) /eixg;    #the replacement
```

I was wondering how would it be possible to name my captures in this context.

For example I would like to call the first one "prefix" the second "number" the third "space" and the fourth "unit"

Comment: There's actually an example of this in the documentation for branch-reset: [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f|pattern%29)

Comment: You could name the capture groups like this `(?<prefix>..)` but why would you? You're just passing them to a function `transformer($+{prefix},...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably can be done like this

```
$recepies =~ s/
     (?|
          (?<prefix> [^\.\/] )                    # (1)
          (?<number> $dimentions )                # (2)
       |  
          (?<prefix> \(? )                        # (1), ex: 1.5
          (?<number> $wholeNumberDecimal )        # (2)
       |  
          (?<prefix> \(? )                        # (1), ex: 1
          (?<number> $wholeNumber )               # (2)
       |  
          (?<prefix> \(? )                        # (1)
          (?<number> $wholeNumberFraction )       # (2)
     )
     (?<space> \s )                          # (3)
     (?<unit> $unit )                        # (4)

/transformer($+{prefix},$+{number},$+{space},$+{unit}) /eixg;    #the replacement
```

*Or like this*

```
$recepies =~ s/
     (?|
          (?<prefix> [^\.\/] )                    # (1)
          (?<number> $dimentions )                # (2)
       |  
          (?<prefix> \(? )                        # (1), ex: 1.5
          (?<number> $wholeNumberDecimal )        # (2)
       |  
          (?<prefix> \(? )                        # (1), ex: 1
          (?<number> $wholeNumber )               # (2)
       |  
          (?<prefix> \(? )                        # (1)
          (?<number> $wholeNumberFraction )       # (2)
     )
     \s
     $unit

/transformer($+{prefix},$+{number},$unit) /eixg;    #the replacement
```

Comment: Great thanks the first one worked. Can you explain what $+{number} means? I am quite new to perl.

Comment: @QasimAhmed - See _perlre_ man page under `Capture Groups` - `Capture group contents are dynamically scoped and available to you outside the pattern until the end of the enclosing block or until the next successful match, whichever comes first. (See "Compound Statements" in perlsyn.) You can refer to them by absolute number (using "$1" instead of "\g1", etc); or by name via the %+ hash, using "$+{name}".`